# How to prove that the roots of this equation are integers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Let there be an equation $a^2 + 4ab + b^2 - 121 = 0$ where I want to prove that a,b are integers. Then I want to find *whether there are* integer values of $b$ for which $a$ is also an integer. Let us consider the case for $a$ $\rightarrow$  $a = \dfrac{-4b \pm \sqrt{16b^2 - 4(b^2-121)}}{2} = -2b \pm \sqrt{3b^2 +121}$ Thereby the problem reduces to showing that $3b^2 +121$ is a perfect square for certain integer values of $b$. This is what I cannot do.

Note: I know I can give examples and all for $3b^2 + 121$ to be a perfect square, but I'm looking for something with a little more substance. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm a little unclear about the original problem. The way you have stated it, I can have non-integer solutions as well.

Comment: Not all solutions of this equation are integral.

Comment: @Wojowu Hmm. Yeah, I had my misgivings. Is there any way to show that there is a pair of $a, b$ for which the equation holds? I know that a,b = 5, 4. But I only found this by plugging in values. And so I have no way of showing that there is an integral solution.

Comment: You have a way of showing existence of integer solutions - providing an example is a perfectly valid method!

Comment: @Wojowu But I'd like a more concrete way... for my own curiosity and personal satisfaction I guess

Comment: Precision matters.  What you want to prove is that a and b *can* both be integers.  Not that they *must* be integers. Obviously there are non-integer solution.  um.. a=0 and b= 11 and a = 0 and b=11 are solutions too.

Comment: $12b^{2} + 4\times 11^{2}$ is a square if and only if $(3b^{2} + 11^{2}) = s^{2} \iff 3|(s-11)(s +11)$ and the smallest positive $s$ for which this happens is $s = 14$, which yields $b^{2} = 5^{2}$.

Comment: To all; there are infinitely many solutions with both $a,b$ integers. Doubtless the original question in some book or contest asked to find at least some of these. Answer posted below.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT:  There are infinitely many integer solutions. They can all be found. In particular, if you have one solution $(a,b)$ you get a new solution with
$$ (a,b) \mapsto (-b, a + 4 b).  $$ Going in the reverse direction,
$$ (a,b) \mapsto ( 4a +  b, -a).  $$ For  solutions to $a^2 + 4ab + b^2 = 121,$ we will almost always need $ab < 0.$

Um. The generator for the (oriented) integer automorphism group of the quadratic form $a^2 + 4ab + b^2$ is
$$
A =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 4
\end{array}
\right),
$$
with inverse
$$
A^{-1} =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
4 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{array}
\right).
$$
The degree two linear recurrences that follow come from applying Cayley-Hamilton to $A,$ in that $A^2 - 4A + I = 0.$

In the original variables, we can collect all solutions into Fibonacci type sequences, as in $a_{n+2} = 4 a_{n+1} - a_n$ and  $b_{n+2} = 4 b_{n+1} - b_n$
$$
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrrr}
 -4736 & -1269 & -340 & -91 & -24 & -5 & 4 & 21 & 80 & 299 & 1116 \\ 
 1269 & 340 & 91 & 24  &  5   &  -4  & -21 & -80 & -299 & -1116 & -4165
\end{array}
$$
We can do the same thing for the solutions where both $(a,b)$ are divisible by $11.$ Oh, not only can we switch the variables, we can always negate both. So $(-5,-4)$ gives us $(5,4)$ and $(4,5).$
$$
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrr}
 -616 & -165 & -44 & -11 & 0 &  11 & 44 & 165 & 616 & 2299  \\ 
 2299 & 616 & 165 & 44  &  11   &  0  & -11 & -44 & -165 & -616 
\end{array}
$$

ORIGINAL: take the invertible change of variables
$$  a = u - 2 v, \;\; \; b = v,$$ so that $a + 2 b = u.$ You have
$$ u^2 - 3 v^2 = 121. $$
There are the imprimitive solutions where $u,v$ are solutions of $u^2 - 3 v^2 = 1$ then multiply both by $11.$
There are infinitely many of these, this is called the Pell equation.

There are also infinitely many imprimitive solutions to $u^2 - 3 v^2 = 121.$ This begins with $1 - 3 \cdot 4 = -11,$ and Brahmagupta's formula leads to  $13^2 - 3 \cdot 4^2 = 11^2.$

In both cases, given values $(u,v),$ changing to $(2u+3v, u + 2 v)$ gives the same value of $u^2 - 3 v^2.$ You should check that, important.

A full accounting of all $(u,v)$ pairs is given by combining the  $(2u+3v, u + 2 v)$ formula with the Conway topograph.

Here are some answers with the topograph , then two books that talk about it:

[Another quadratic Diophantine equation: How do I proceed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81917/another-quadratic-diophantine-equation-how-do-i-proceed/144794#144794)

[How to find solutions of $x^2-3y^2=-2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228356/how-to-find-solutions-of-x2-3y2-2/228405#228405)

[Generate solutions of Quadratic Diophantine Equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/342284/generate-solutions-of-quadratic-diophantine-equation/345128#345128)

[Finding all solutions of the Pell-type equation $x^2-5y^2 = -4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512621/finding-all-solutions-of-the-pell-type-equation-x2-5y2-4/512649#512649)

[how to solve binary form $ax^2+bxy+cy^2=m$, for integer and rational $ (x,y)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739752/how-to-solve-binary-form-ax2bxycy2-m-for-integer-and-rational-x-y/739765#739765)

[Find all integer solutions for the equation $|5x^2 - y^2| = 4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/742181/find-all-integer-solutions-for-the-equation-5x2-y2-4/756972#756972)

[Maps of primitive vectors and Conway's river, has anyone built this in SAGE?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1078450/maps-of-primitive-vectors-and-conways-river-has-anyone-built-this-in-sage/1078979#1078979)

[Infinitely many systems of $23$ consecutive integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1091310/infinitely-many-systems-of-23-consecutive-integers/1093382#1093382)

[Finding integers of the form $3x^2 + xy - 5y^2$ where $x$ and $y$ are integers, using diagram via arithmetic progression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1132799/finding-integers-of-the-form-3x2-xy-5y2-where-x-and-y-are-integers)

[Small integral representation as $x^2-2y^2$ in Pell's equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1221178/small-integral-representation-as-x2-2y2-in-pells-equation/1221280#1221280)

[Solving the equation $ x^2-7y^2=-3 $ over integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1404023/solving-the-equation-x2-7y2-3-over-integers/1404126#1404126)

[Solutions to Diophantine Equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1599211/solutions-to-diophantine-equations/1600010#1600010)

http://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/the-sensual-quadratic-form   (Conway)

http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387955872             (Stillwell)

I'm afraid I was not able to fit this entire diagram onto one page. However, combine this with [How to find solutions of $x^2-3y^2=-2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228356/how-to-find-solutions-of-x2-3y2-2/228405#228405)
and you get ***all*** integer expressions for $u^2 - 3 v^2 = 121,$ which then lead to all $a^2 + 4ab + b^2 = 121.$

[image]

All solutions  $(u,v)$ come from the transformation $(2u+3v, u + 2 v),$ its inverse  $(2u-3v, -u + 2 v),$ and the three triples
$$ (11,0), (13,4),(14,5) $$
Some care is need for the original $(a,b)$ problem because the change of variables does not quite keep positivity. Indeed, instead of the $\pm$ symmetries, the original variables have $(a,b)$ going to $(b,a).$

Comment: I'm gonna be honest with you. You lost me after $u^2 - 3v^2 = 121$. As you've probably guessed, I have no experience in number theory. I am just a beginner in high school and I'm trying to learn the works of the trade. So if you could give some more layman explanations, that would be great.

Comment: Furthermore, is there a way to find the solutions to this equation using no number theory at all? (Or at the most, very basic number theory?)

Comment: I've edited my question to include a more basic, straightforward approach which I believe could work. Could you follow up on it, if you have the time?

Comment: @S.Mo who gave you this question and why did they do that? What did they hope you would accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

From $a^2+b^2+4ab-121=0$ we get $(a+b)^2+2ab=121$
Or $2=\frac{11+a+b}{a} \frac{11-a-b}{b}$
Now case 1: when the factors on right hand side are integers and coprime. Since 2 has only 2 factors, one of these has to be 1 and the other 2 
 Taking $\frac{11+a+b}{a}=2$ and $\frac{11-a-b}{b}=1$ we get $a=11 , b=0$

 Similarly $\frac{11+a+b}{a}=1$ and $\frac{11-a-b}{b}=2$ gives $a=44$ and $b=-11$

I can't do the case where those factors are not integers or coprime right now (note that's the case of $a=5,b=4$)