# Small integral representation as $x^2-2y^2$ in Pell's equation

Tags: arithmetic, algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-forms, pell-type-equations

Let $k$ be a "representable" positive integer, in the sense
that $k=|x^2-2y^2|$ for some integers $x,y$. Does it necessarily
follow that $k$ can also be represented with small parameters,
i.e. $k=|u^2-2v^2|$ with $|u|\leq\sqrt{k},|v|\leq\sqrt{k}$ ?

My (mostly useless) thoughts : if $N$ is very big and $a_N,b_N$
are the unique integers such that $a_N+b_N\sqrt{2}=(\sqrt{2}-1)^N(x+y\sqrt{2})$,
then $|a_N+b_N\sqrt{2}|$ can be arbitrarily small, but unfortunately
that doesn't make the individual $a_N$ and $b_N$ small.

Also, we know that $k$ is representable iff all the prime divisors of
$k$ are such that $2$ is a quadratic residue to them, but that doesn't seem
to help either.

Comment: just realized the possible significance of your absolute value signs. If you are willing to have, with $k >0,$ the representation $u^2 - 2 v^2 = -k,$ then you actually do achieve the bounds you wanted, $$ u \leq \sqrt k, \; \;  v \leq \sqrt k. $$ Diagram and summary edited into answer.

Comment: Not by the way, $-k$ is represented if and only if $k$ is represented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appendix 1: all pairs $(u,v)$ in the tree depicted satisfy $u \geq 2v.$ As a result, 
$$ k = u^2 - 2 v^2 \geq 4 v^2 - 2v^2 = 2 v^2,  $$
so $$2 v^2 \leq k$$
and $$ \color{blue}{ v \leq \sqrt {\frac{k}{2}}}. $$

Appendix 2:
we may demand
$$ v \leq \frac{u}{2}. $$
Therefore
$$  2 v^2 \leq \frac{u^2}{2}, $$
$$  -2 v^2 \geq - \frac{u^2}{2}, $$
$$ k = u^2 -2 v^2 \geq u^2 - \frac{u^2}{2} =  \frac{u^2}{2}, $$
$$ u^2 \leq 2 k,  $$
$$ \color{blue}{ u \leq \sqrt {2k}}. $$

preliminary: I already think you are roughly correct. The Conway topograph method deals most directly with $u+v$ when both are positive. The largest variables come from
$$ u = 2n + 1, \; \; v = n, \; \;  u^2 - 2 v^2 = 2 n^2 + 4 n + 1  $$ 
Note that this "branch" of the tree illustrates both inequalities well, $  u \leq \sqrt {2k} $ and $  v \leq \sqrt {\frac{k}{2}}. $

I have answered several questions with these diagrams, also the book describing the method is at [CONWAY](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/conwaysens.pdf).  The point is that any (positive) number represented occurs in the first tree on the positive side of the river:

[image]
[image]

Just noticed the absolute values in the original question. If you are willing to represent $-k$ instead of $k,$ you get the bounds you wanted. This happens in an upside-down tree below the river where we have $u^2 - 2 v^2 = -k$ for positive $k,$ and with $u,v > 0$ and $v \geq u.$ Similar arguments to the above give your desired bounds, 
$$  u \leq \sqrt k, \; \; \;  v \leq \sqrt k. $$

[image]

Comment: @EwanDelanoy, that is the real story, how we decide on size of a pair $(u,v).$ I just got one case which gives an explicit bound on $v.$ Typing...

Comment: "we may demand $v\leq \frac{u}{2}$" in appendix 2? How so ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy, every (primitively) represented positive number is represented in the tree depicted; any two $(u,v)$ pairs in the tree, depicted as a (green) column vector, have $u \geq 2 v,$ and add up to a new pair one number out which still satisfies $u \geq 2v,$ as $(3,1) + (5,2) = (8,3).$

Comment: @EwanDelanoy, I suspect you can make an argument with no diagrams, given positive $(u,v)$ with positive $k$ and the ratio $v/u$ not big enough, repeatedly use the mappng $$ (u,v) \mapsto (3u-4v, -2u+3v) $$

Comment: The question has now become, can $|u|\leq \sqrt{2k}$ be strengthened to $|u|\leq \sqrt{k}$ ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy, no, in the middle I give the example along the right branch, $u = 2n+1, v=n, k = 2n^2 + 4 n + 1.$ For prime $k$ we are allowed only one $(u,v)$ pair in this tree. For example, $k=31.$