# To find all integral solutions of $3x^2 - 4y^2 = 11$

Tags: number-theory

I have to find all integral solutions of $3x^2 - 4y^2 = 11$.

I looked at the equation $\text{mod}\ 3$, and $\text{mod}\ 4$ to see that $x^2 \equiv 1\ \text{mod}\ 4$ and $y^2 \equiv 1\ \text{mod}\ 3$

How do I proceed from here? Or is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: Did you mean "integer solutions"?

Comment: @AsBk3397 "integral" is the adjective form of "integer". It is grammatically and mathematically correct.

Comment: Oh, sorry for that then. I have never seen that before so I thought it may be a typo but thank you for the information as well.

Comment: [program](https://tio.run/##XY2xDoMgFEVn@Yo3wgtV0bqY8C2GRq0k9klRE/x6lA4OvcNZTnKuO7ZpoTpGu3brdzd@AA2z@bx6A9Ra2jghlnkjECutibFx8RDAEnhD74E3UpW/yUq0LLMj3CHOawwYHkqJongmmzmfikEm/mnE60TEeAI)

Comment: I was hoping for a more 'mathematical answer'. But thanks for this

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2579293/to-find-all-integral-solutions-of-3x2-4y2-11/2579305#2579305

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two good books. I have given more detailed answers for many of this type of problem.

http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/conwaysens.pdf

https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/TN/TNbook.pdf

Here is a good one http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739752/how-to-solve-binary-form-ax2bxycy2-m-for-integer-and-rational-x-y/739765#739765

As $11$ is prime, there are two orbits; one sequence of $x$ values is
$$ 3, \; \; 37, \; \; 515, \; \; 7173, \ldots  $$
with $$ x_{n+2} = 14 x_{n+1} - x_n,  $$ with matching $y$ values
$$  2, \; \; 32, \; \;  446, \; \; 6212, \ldots  $$
$$ y_{n+2} = 14 y_{n+1} - y_n.  $$

Here is the second orbit:
sequence of $x$ values is
$$ 5, \; \; 67, \; \; 933, \; \; 12995, \ldots  $$
with $$ x_{n+2} = 14 x_{n+1} - x_n,  $$ with matching $y$ values
$$  4, \; \; 58, \; \;  808, \; \; 11254, \ldots  $$
$$ y_{n+2} = 14 y_{n+1} - y_n.  $$

The linear recurrences above come from Cayley-Hamilton for the matrix
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
7 & 8 \\
6 & 7 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

[image]

Comment: Can you give more context? Orbit is from group theory? Is this some generalization of Pell's equation?

Comment: I'm interested. How do you know that there are two orbits?

Comment: @mvw see references I put in the answer now. Worth the effort to draw the topograph for $3x^2 - 4 y^2,$ out enough layers to find all occurrences of $11.$

Comment: @KennyLau see references I put in the answer now. Worth the effort to draw the topograph for $3x^2 - 4 y^2,$ out enough layers to find all occurrences of $11.$

Comment: Can it be one orbit if we propagate the recursion in both directions?

Comment: That is great stuff. Thank you very much.

Comment: @OscarLanzi yes, exactly. I have posted the diagram, enough for you to run the automorphism (inverse matrix) backwards and get negative $y,$ repeating the other orbit of positive $x,y$

Comment: @mvw I put in part of the diagram. The linear recursion is Cayley-Hamilton for the "automorphism" matrix

Comment: This is a very interesting approach. Thank you! Especially for the resources