# Which integers are the sum of $k$ positive squares?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, square-numbers

For each $k$, is there something we can say about each positive integer being able to be written as a sum of $k$ positive squares? What is known for $k > 5$? What about if we only care about whether a prime can be written as a sum of $k$ positive squares for each given $k$?

During my investigation, I found a lot of results.

For $k=2$, a simple test on the prime factors and exponentes can be made, which can be seen in the "FORMULA" section of [this OEIS page](https://oeis.org/A000404).

For $k=3$, it seems that no definitive rule has been found, but there are some interesting facts in [this OEIS page](https://oeis.org/A000408)

For $k=4$, I have found very few information [in the OEIS page](https://oeis.org/A000414)

For $k=5$, even less information is found [in the OEIS page](https://oeis.org/A047700)

I have also found this [interesting OEIS page](https://oeis.org/wiki/Sums_of_squares) about sums of squares.

So what about $k > 5$? Is there anything interesting about the sum of $k$ positive squares? And what if we restrict ourselves to primes?

Comment: But the "interesting" page says: "Please do not rely on any information it contains." For six positive squares and more see for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2816303/integer-as-sum-of-6-positive-squares).

Comment: better information for $k=4,5$  at the "complement"  pages  https://oeis.org/A000534  ....

https://oeis.org/A047701   ......   general facts in Halter-Koch  
http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa42/aa4212.pdf

Comment: I have the fifth edition of Niven, Zuckerman, Montgomery. The simple facts about four or five nonzero squares are on pages 317-319, especially Corollary 6.27. More detail about four is in Conway, The Sensual Quadratic Form, especially the Theorem on page 140